# Confusing while set active class in multiple level list menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I will write active class as following code. but some time multiple level menu get confusing active class. some `li` are not expanding.

```
<li class="treeview @(ViewBag.Controller == "Employee" ? "active" : "")  @(ViewBag.Controller == "Manpower" ? "active" : "") " style="display:none">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i> <span>Personnel Management</span><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu  @(ViewBag.Controller == "Employee" ? "menu-open" : "") @(ViewBag.Controller == "Manpower" ? "menu-open" : "")">
        <li class="@(ViewBag.Title == "Employees" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Employee Detail", "Index", "Employee", new { style = "color:red" })</li>
        <li class="@(ViewBag.Title == "Manpower" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Manpower Tracking for Projects", "ManpowerTracking", "Manpower", new { style = "color:red" })</li>
        <li class="@(ViewBag.Title == "Manpower" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Manpower Expenses Claims", "Index", "Manpower", new { style = "color:red" })</li>
        <li class="@(ViewBag.Title == "Manpower Report" ? "active" : "")">
            <a href="#"> <span>Reports</span><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu @(ViewBag.Controller == "Manpower" ? "menu-open" : "")">
                <li class="@(ViewBag.Action == "ClaimsReports" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Claims Reports", "ClaimsReports", "Manpower", new { style = "color:red" })</li>
                <li class="@(ViewBag.Action == "ManpowerReports" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Manpower Reports", "ManpowerReports", "Manpower", new { style = "color:red" })</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
</li>
```

Comment: it depends what are you using for expanding that menus :) jquery? or css3 ?

Comment: In that MVC, Call ViewBag message from page that identifies controller name and set active or empty.

Comment: :( cant help then sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly impossible to say why it may not be working. For some reason, your conditionals aren't working as you expect them to, but as to why, who knows? There's no enough here to say.

However, in general, I can tell you that this is an extremely brittle way handle this, especially matching based on `ViewBag.Title`. If someone later decides to change that title to something else, your menu breaks. Traditionally, it's best to match by URL:

```
@{ string url; }
...

@{ url = Url.Action("Index", "Employee"); }
<li class="@(Request.Url.AbsolutePath == url ? "active" : "")">
    <a href="@url" style="color:red">Employee Detail</a>
</li>
```

Comment: this is right but, how to set second level or third level menu having different controllers

Comment: If you have a true hierarchy in your URLs, you could just use `Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains(url)`. For example, if the current URL is `/foo/bar`, and the URL for the parent menu item is `/foo`, then it would match. If not, you can continue to test against the controller name, that's slightly brittle, but as long as your controller names don't change, you should be fine. It's definitely better than using something like `ViewBag.Title`.